# error state for swing input elements

Tags: java, swing, highlight

I'm creating input validation for checking valid relationships between different fields. so if entered data is wrong, I want to mark out wrong component.

e.g. if one field not populated, it must be highlighted

it's possible to convert component into any error state? e.g. jtextfield, jcombobox...

Comment: *it's possible to convert component into any error state? e.g. red highlighting* - Yes

Comment: Show us some of your works..your GUI layout .. your code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`JComponent#setBackground()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color)), for example:

```
txt.setBackground(new Color(255, 186, 186));
```

[image]

or maybe setting a red color for the text? [`JComponent#setForeground()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setForeground(java.awt.Color))

```
txt.setForeground(Color.RED);
```

[image]